# Rotated table iteration

Tags: c#, java, c, algorithm, loops

I have two arbitrary sized square tables, that need to be iterated in very specific order, picture below shows rectangles of size 4x4 with values describing the order:

[image: Rectangles]

I have a function `F(row,col)` I need two most efficient loops that will iterate through the tables using previously described order and call F(row, call) inside them

Thank you,

Comment: And what progress have you made?

Comment: What does your function F do? Is your question only about performance, or do you have problems getting the rotation to work?

Comment: I've spent few hours already writing that loop, either I'm drunk which is not, or I don't know what might be the reason that blocking me

Comment: I just need to perform iteration, in more or less optimal way

Comment: That's funny Eric, try to write that loop before making jokes

Comment: Rotating a square matrix.. yum yum :D

Comment: Try thinking in diagonals http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372321/how-could-i-add-the-values-of-a-matrix-int-diagonally-from-bottomleft-to-top

Comment: Thank you everyone! Now when I see how this loop looks like, it is even more embarrassing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for the first and second square:

```java
for (int i = 0, n = size + size - 1; i < n; i++) {
    int j = min(i, size - 1);
    for (int col = i - j; col <= j; col++) {
        int row = i - col;

        /* case 1 */
        F(row, col);

        /* case 2 */
        F(size - row - 1, size - col - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work, it would call F(0,0), F(0,-1), F(0,-2) .. F(1,0) etc.

Answer (score 1):

For the first case, try this (I'm assuming you are using zero-based indexes, if you preffer 1-based, just use `F(row + 1, col + 1)`):

```
int DIM = 3; // dimention of the table - 1, in this case 4 (4 - 1 = 3)

int col = 0;
int row = 0;

for(int x = 0; x < (DIM + 1) * (DIM + 1); x++) {
    F(row, col);  // your function
    int lastRow = row;
    row = (col == DIM)? DIM: (row == 0? col + 1: row - 1);
    col = (col == DIM)? lastRow + 1: (lastRow == 0? 0: col + 1);
}
```

for the second case, its almost the same, the difference is how you call your function (same as in the other case, if you are using 1-based, replace the parameters in your function by `F(DIM - row + 1, DIM - col + 1)`):

```
int col = 0;
int row = 0;

for(int x = 0; x < (DIM + 1) * (DIM + 1); x++) {
    F(DIM - row, DIM - col);  // your function
    int lastRow = row;
    row = (col == DIM)? DIM: (row == 0? col + 1: row - 1);
    col = (col == DIM)? lastRow + 1: (lastRow == 0? 0: col + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you morgano, I had to choose Thomas's response as answer since he answered first, but up-vote goes for you and bunch of your other answers!